# validation on objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am beginner in iPhone app developing.I am creating an iPhone app which have a user interface with 3 text boxes for taking user input (textbox1, textbox2 and textbox3)say for UserName, MailAddress and TelephoneNumber
 and a button(ok) with touch up inside event for action event.

user must fill all the text box with data compulsorily to proceed by clicking ok button.When all text boxes are filled alert message saying thank you must be generated.

If not done so alert view should be generated.

But What i want to do is:

- If all text boxes are empty alert should be displayed with alert message saying UserName, MailAddress and TelephoneNumber is not entered.
- If only UserName is not filled by user, alert should be displayed with alert message saying UserName is not entered.
- If only MailAddress is not filled by user, alert should be displayed with alert message saying MailAddress is not entered.
- If only TelephoneNumber is not filled by user, alert should be displayed with alert message saying TelephoneNumber is not entered.
- if both UserName and MailAddress is not filled by user, alert should be displayed with alert message saying UserName and MailAddress is not entered.
- if both UserName and TelephoneNumber is not filled by user, alert should be displayed with alert message saying UserName and TelephoneNumber is not entered.
- if both MailAddress and TelephoneNumber is not filled by user, alert should be displayed with alert message saying MailAddress and TelephoneNumber is not entered.

How can I do this in objective c? Is there any easy method??? 
I have to do it by using function so that It can call the required function to display an required alert message accordingly the user input when user taps the ok button without filling all required data.

Comment: check my answer with code link

Comment: But this is not like a question to ask, I was free thats why I solved it.... It is just a basic programming logical question irrespective of any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the [code](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5386727/umtvalidation-zip-38k?da=y)...

```
NSInteger user, mail, telephone;
user=mail=telephone=0;

if (![self.userName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    user=1;
}
if (![self.mail.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    mail=2;
}
if (![self.telephone.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    telephone=4;
}

NSString *warningString=[NSString new];
switch (user+mail+telephone) {
    case 0:
        warningString=@"Please enter user, mail and telephone.";
        break;
    case 1:
        warningString=@"Please enter mail and telephone.";
        break;
    case 2:
        warningString=@"Please enter user and telephone.";
        break;
    case 3:
        warningString=@"Please enter telephone.";
        break;
    case 4:
        warningString=@"Please enter user and mail.";
        break;
    case 5:
        warningString=@"Please enter  mail.";
        break;
    case 6:
        warningString=@"Please enter user.";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
NSLog(@"-->%@",warningString);
if (user+mail+telephone < 7) {

    UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:warningString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: ya how can i create a method and do that. I am not used to doing such.Please can u hel me with the code??

Comment: -(void)showValidationAlert:(NSString *)alertMessage{ //display alert here }

Comment: can u give me full code?? being beginner i cannot understand properly :(

Comment: havent you studied any language like C /C++ ? this is the vey basic. I gave you the idea and implementing is very easy just coding, and it will take 20 minutes... you want me to do that... try yaar. if you stuck then u can contant me... I will help u for sure. my mail id is there in my  profile.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to disable the button unless all items are filled in correctly?

It means less fiddling about with code to see what has and has not been entered. And it's a faster way of providing feedback - as you don't have to to through the rigmarole of pressing a key to find out if your data has been accepted, and then pressing a button to dismiss an alert view to go back to edit the input.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i appreciate your idea very much.Thanks for that.But the problem is i have to do it by using function as told by my mentor. So can u help me doing this by using function call??? please..

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the textField has data or not as

```
if (userNameField.text.length == 0)
{
NSLog (@"Username is not being entered");
}
else
{
NSLog (@"Username Field has some data ");
}
```

Similarly you can make appropriate conditions as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for idea.i need to do this by using function call. I have done this by using simple if else but the problem is i have to compulsorily do it by using function as told by teacher.. so I asked this how i cud do by function call. Please can u help mw with that..

Comment: then create a function as
-(BOOL)checkWhetherUserNameFieldHasData

Comment: then create a function as
-(BOOL)checkWhetherTextFieldHasData:(UITextField *)textfeild
{
  return textfeild.text.length;
}
Now in above code simply call this function in all your if else statements and pass the textfield you want to check like this
if ([self checkWhetherTextFieldHasData: userNameField])
or if ([self checkWhetherTextFieldHasData: mailAddressField])
or if ([self checkWhetherTextFieldHasData: telephoneNumberField])
Kindly accept my answer if it resolves your problem :)

Answer (score -1):

validations in Objective C are same as in simple C++ or any other languages.

You have to set the conditions like

```
if(textbox1.text.lenght == 0)
{
     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Enter User      Name" message: nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alertView show];
}
else if(textbox2.text.lenght == 0)
{
  //alert Message
}
```

Regards

Abhishek Goyal